Standard Fields from User are not available in permission sets
I need to give Read permission to Email field in the User object.
But I am not able to see this field in the My Permission Set-> Object Settings->User.
I tried to access the Email field via link link this: https://myorg.sandbox.lightning.force.com/lightning/setup/ObjectManager/User/FieldsAndRelationships/Email/view
But Field Level Security button is not there so not able to verify if the field is readable or not.
Is anybody aware how can we make sure that the Email field from User object have read permission in the permision set.

Hypothesis - if you have CRUD on User, then required fields are always FLS true; for example, a Permission Set on Account always has Account.Name with FLS true

Email is a required field, you could check on User Object Referece, therefore you cannot add it to a permission set.
Everyone who can access an object already has read permission on required fields.
Indeed, if you try to edit the object settins against any object that has a required field you won't be able to change those FLS.
Moreover if you try to add a field permission related to a required field in the xml of a permission set and then deploy it, you'll get an error stating:

You cannot deploy to a required field

